# Upper bound on minimum number of prime factors in short intervals

Tags: nt.number-theory, analytic-number-theory, arithmetic-functions

Suppose that $H = H(X)$ is some quantity growing with $X$. Are there any bounds on $$F(X, H) = \min_{X < n\le X + H} \omega(n)?$$
It isn't hard to obtain a lower bound $\max_{x\sim X} F(X, H)\gg \frac{\log X}{H\log\log X}$. Also, for $H\gg X^\delta$, I believe it follows from a standard lower bound sieve the bound $F(X, H)\ll \delta^{-1}$. Is anything better known in either direction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is some useful information in the paper [P. Erdôs and I. Kátai. On the growth of some additive functions of small intervals. Acta Math. Hungar. 33 (1979), 345-359.](https://P.%20Erd%C3%B4s%20and%20I.%20K%C3%A1tai.%20On%20the%20growth%20of%20some%20additive%20functions%20of%20small%20intervals.%20Acta%20Math.%20Hungar.%2033%20(1979),%20345-359.)

Let $$O_{k}(n)=\max _{j=1, \ldots, k} \omega(n+j), \quad o_{k}(n)=\min _{j=1, \ldots, k} \omega(n+j).$$
Then (see *I. Kátai. Local growth of the number of the divisors of consecutive integers. Publ. Math. Debrecen 18 (1971), 171-175.*) for every $\varepsilon>0$, apart from a set of $n$'s having zero density, the inequalities
$$
O_{k}(n) \leqq(1+\varepsilon) \varrho\left(\frac{\log k}{\log \log n}\right) \log \log n, \quad o_{k}(n) \geqq(1-\varepsilon) \bar{\varrho}\left(\frac{\log k}{\log \log n}\right) \log \log n
$$
hold for every $k=1,2, \ldots$ Here $\varrho(u)$ $(u \ge 0)$ is defined as the inverse function of $\psi(z)=z \log \frac{z}{e}+1$ defined in $z \ge 1$, and $\bar{\varrho}(n)$ $(n \ge 0)$ is the inverse function of the same $\psi(z)$ defined in $0<z \le 1$. In the same paper it was conjectured that
$$
O_{k}(n) \geqq(1-\varepsilon) \varrho\left(\frac{\log k}{\log \log n}\right) \log \log n
$$
and
$$
o_{k}(n) \leqq(1+\varepsilon) \bar{\varrho}\left(\frac{\log k}{\log \log n}\right) \log \log n
$$

They prove that for every $\varepsilon>0$ these irequalities hold for every $k \ge 1$, apart from a set of $n$'s having zero density.